# How to purposely duplicate specific rows in SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I want to duplicate a specific teacher so that they appear twice in the output of a `SELECT` statement.

| Teacher | Grade | District |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mr. Smith | 3rd | West |
| Mrs. John | 4th | South |
| Mr. Cameron | 2nd | North |
| Mr. Cameron | 2nd | North |
| Kirk Horn | 1st | West |

Desired result, after duplicating 'Mr. Cameron':

| Teacher | Grade | District |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mr. Smith | 3rd | West |
| Mrs. John | 4th | South |
| Mr. Cameron | 2nd | North |
| Mr. Cameron | 2nd | North |
| Mr. Cameron | 2nd | North |
| Mr. Cameron | 2nd | North |
| Kirk Horn | 1st | West |

What would a `SELECT` statement look like - without creating a new a table?

I want to do something like this but without the `INSERT`:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142414/easiest-way-to-duplicate-rows

Comment: What is your `select` statement? In your first data above, is that from a table or are you inserting that into a table?

Comment: Use  `union all`

Comment: @ErgestBasha `union all` and just add a where clause for specifically Mr. Cameron?

I think I want to do something like this but without the insert statement since the table returned is the result of a select statement.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142414/easiest-way-to-duplicate-rows

Comment: Why is Mr. Cameron being duplicated? what's the logic behind it?

Comment: @mike_mussini added an answer with example. Something like that , but you need union all which doesn't remove duplicates

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? The solution can differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table is big, and the filter is not selective and backed by an index, then this "trick" avoids a second sequential scan over the table - using **PostgreSQL**:

```sql
SELECT t.*  -- or your list of columns
FROM   test t
     , generate_series(1, CASE WHEN t.teacher = 'Mr. Cameron' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y-dlvGts)

It's short syntax for a `LATERAL` join. See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vWfL-QQa)

If you need more copies, just replace *'2'* above.

Postgres has a hard time estimating the number of rows to expect with this construct, which may confuse query planning. [Stu's variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73953511/939860) (doing the same) is slightly more expensive, but easier to estimate for query planning. Syntax needs to be adapted for Postgres:

```sql
SELECT teacher, grade, district
FROM   test t
JOIN   LATERAL (VALUES (1),(2)) x(v) ON v = 1 OR teacher = 'Mr. Cameron';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y-dlvGts)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UNION ALL`

```
select Teacher,Grade,District
from test
union all
select Teacher,Grade,District
from test 
where Teacher='Mr. Cameron'
order by Teacher;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/rBpSL8NW

If you want to force/predict how many duplicate values for `Mr. Cameron` you will add ,try below query which add only one duplicate value `limit 1`

```
(select Teacher,Grade,District
 from test
 )
union all
(
select Teacher,Grade,District
from test 
where Teacher='Mr. Cameron'
limit 1 
  );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/uUX5QD3F